# image and h4 elements are not coming side by side in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I am uisng material ui in react. Trying to put the image and h4 adjacent. but they align vertically. I tried to adjust the width but not working.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import robo from "./robo.png";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  logo: {
    width: 100,
  },
  name: {
    width: 100,
  },
});
const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <img alt="Gyrodata" src={robo} className={classes.logo} />
      <h4 className={classes.name}>Maersk Invincible</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H4` is a block level element, that's why it moved to the next line. You can use `flex` to make them inline or make `h4` an inline element using `display` property.

In below code, I've used `flex` to make the `children` appear in the same row. You can find more information on `flex` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and its supported by all major browsers now.

`Your updated code.`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import robo from "./robo.png";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 100,
  },
  name: {
    width: 100,
  },
});
const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <img alt="Gyrodata" src={robo} className={classes.logo} />
      <h4 className={classes.name}>Maersk Invincible</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set display for child elements or display flex for parent elements.

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import robo from "./robo.png";
    import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      logo: {
        width: 100,
display:"inline-block"
      },
      name: {
        width: 100,
display:"inline-block"
      },
    });
    const Home = () => {
      const classes = useStyles();
    
      return (
        <div>
          <img alt="Gyrodata" src={robo} className={classes.logo} />
          <h4 className={classes.name}>Maersk Invincible</h4>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Home;
```